# Passing paramters to import

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to pass params to maat excel import.
I'm doing somethig like this:

JS:

v-for option in options

v-model selection

form = new formData

form.append(users.xls, this.selection)

Controller:

```
{
    Excel::import(new UsersImport, 'users.xlsx');
}
```

Import class:

```
class UsersImport implements ToCollection
{
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        foreach ($rows as $row) 
        {
            User::create([
                'name' => $row[0],
                'option' => use the selection here
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Question im asking is how to get `this.selection` into the `option` column through the controller and import class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a constructor to your class and pass it to the constructor:

```
public function __construct($selection)
{
    $this->selection = $selection;
}

// then in the Controller

Excel::import(new UsersImport($something), 'users.xlsx');
```

Then you can use it in your method as `$this->selection`.

Comment: Thank you.  Can you please tell me what   $something  refers to?

Comment: what ever you are passing to the server as `this.selected` from vue

Comment: Thanks, opened a whole new world!